# Configuring Keycloak OIDC with an nginx (OpenResty) reverse-proxy

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, keycloak, openid-connect, openresty

I am experimenting with a two-service docker-compose recipe, largely based on
the following GitHub project:

```
https://github.com/rongfengliang/keycloak-openresty-openidc
```

After streamlining, my configuration looks something like the following fork
commit:

```
https://github.com/Tythos/keycloak-openresty-openidc
```

My current issue is, the authorization endpoint ("../openid-connect/auth") uses
the internal origin ("http://keycloak-svc:"). Obviously, if users are
redirected to this URL, their browsers will need to cite the external origin
("http://localhost:"). I thought the PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING variable for the
Keycloak service would fix this, but I'm wondering if I need to do something
like a rewrite on-the-fly in the nginx/openresty configuration.

To replicate, from project root::

> docker-compose build

> docker-compose up --force-recreate --remove-orphans

Then browse to "http://localhost:8090" to start the OIDC flow. You can
circumvent the origin issue by, once you encounter the aforementioned origin
issue, by replacing "keycloak-svc" with "localhost", which will forward you to
the correct login interface. Once there, though, you will need to add a user
to proceed. To add a user, browse to "http://localhost:8080" in a separate tab
and follow these steps before returning to the original tab and entering the
credentials:

- Under Users > Add user:

  - username = "testuser"
  - email = "{{whatever}}"
  - email verified = ON
  - Groups > add "restybox-group"
- After user created:

  - Go to "Credentials" tab
  - Set to "mypassword"
  - Temporary = OFF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authorization Servers such as Keycloak have a base / internet URL when running behind a reverse proxy. You don't need to do anything dynamic in the reverse proxy - have a look at the [frontend URL configuration](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#default-provider).

Out of interest I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70836338/ory-hydra-403-with-reverse-proxy), that may help you to understand the general pattern. Aim for good URLs (not localhost) and a discovery endpoint that returns intermet URLs rather than internal URLs.

Comment: Most groovy. Upon closer inspection, based on your feedback, the KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL environmental variable was set to "http://localhost:8080/auth" (see recent commit if you are coming upon this later in history), and the PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING environmental variable was removed entirely. Not only does this address the frontend address issues (after a few try-fail iterations on the exact value), it even passes the successful authorization back through the correct flow now. Wonderful. The official Docker Hub page for jboss/keycloak was also useful: https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak